# Google+ Follow Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-plus, social-networking

I'm adding social media button to a website to follow / like a specific page and looking through Google's documentation on adding a follow button to your website, all I can see is their pre-made buttons:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/

What I want to do is have a little image of their logo and when this image is clicked, open up a box in a popup or new window to follow a Google+ page. Is there any URL I can put as a href around the image or some JavaScript to use instead of having to use the button that Google's JavaScript generates as it is a total pain to style.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[See The Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Y7Q/)**

```
<a href="https://plusone.google.com/" onclick="popUp=window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOUR WEBSITE URL', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=400');popUp.focus();return false">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/" alt="Google+" title="Google+"/>
</a>
```